# .htacess redirect 301 doesn't work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have issue to redirect 301 URLs,

I want to redirect from **fr.example.com/fr** to **www.example.com/fr-ch**
the rest of the URL doesnt have always same structure but htaccess redirect to same structure, 
exemple:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\. [NC]
Redirect 301    /fr   https://www.example.com/fr-ch         
Redirect 301    /fr/coffee/arabica-robusta  https://www.example.com/fr-ch/ccc/arabica-robusta
```

what I get as result is redirect to
 https://www.example.com/fr-ch/coffee/arabica-robusta

and not to

https://www.example.com/fr-ch/ccc/arabica-robusta

Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect EXACTLY /fr, so you need to add `^` in the beginning and `$` at the end.

So this should work :

```
Redirect 301    ^/fr$   https://www.example.com/fr-ch
```